# OCamlで例外からスタックトレースを取得する方法

Tags: ocaml, exception

OCamlでexn型の値からスタックトレースを取得する方法はありますでしょうか？JavaのgetStackTrace()のような。

標準のPrintexcモジュールを探したのですが、現在のスタックトレースを取得する Printexc.get_backtrace はあるものの、例外からこしらえる方法が分かりませんでした。

参考: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printexc.html

例えば次のようなプログラムで、work関数が失敗したときのスタックトレースを処理したいことなどがあります。

```
open Batteries

let work () = ...

let _ =
  match wrap work () with
  | Ok result -> print_endline result
  | Bad e ->
     (* ここでスタックトレースも出力したい *)
     prerr_endline (Printexc.to_string e);
     exit 1
```

コマンドラインのシステムなら単純にraiseで例外を投げてしまうのもアリかもしれませんが、ログファイルに保存したり、DBに保存したりしたいこともあると思うのです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml 4.03.0, batteries.2.5.2 で次のプログラムを環境変数 `OCAMLRUNPARAM` に `b` を設定するとバックトレースは出力されます:

```
(* with export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b *)
(* ocamlfind ocamlopt -package batteries -linkpkg -o z.exe z.ml *)
open Batteries

let work () = 
  let rec f = function
    | 0 -> raise Exit
    | n -> f (n-1) ^ "x"
  in
  f 10

let _ =
  match wrap work () with
  | Ok result -> print_endline result
  | Bad e ->
     prerr_endline @@ Printexc.get_backtrace ();
     prerr_endline @@ Printexc.to_string e;
     exit 1
```

以下が私の環境での出力です:

```
Raised at file "z.ml", line 5, characters 21-25
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "z.ml", line 6, characters 15-22
Called from file "src/batInnerPervasives.mlv", line 59, characters 22-27

Pervasives.Exit
```

質問者の環境でなぜトレースが出力されないのかわかりませんが、一般的には環境変数 `OCAMLRUNPARAM` を設定していない事が多いです。

なお、`get_backtrace` や `print_backtrace` は最後の例外発生時のスタックトレースを得るものです。「現在のスタックトレース」をとるものではありません。また、例外自体はスタックトレースを持っていません。

Comment: Printexc.get_backtrace の意味を勘違いしていました。
また、OCAMLRUNPARAM=bはコンパイル時ではなく、実行時に設定が必要というところを間違えてうまくスタックトレースがでていなかったというところもありました。